# An isotope of a radioactive element has half-life equal to 9 thousand years.

Tags: calculus

An isotope of a radioactive element has half-life equal to 9 thousand years.
Imagine a sample that is so old that most of its radioactive atoms have decayed, leaving just 15 percent of the initial quantity of the isotope remaining. how old is the sample:

my attmept:  $The \;half\; means\; that\; the\; isotope\; is \;cut\; IN\; HALF \;each\; it\; hits\; 9,000\; years\\
\therefore R=I\times .5^(y/t)\\
R\;is\;that\;is\;left\;, I\;is\;the\;what\;you\;start\;with\;,y\;is\;the\;how\;long\;it\;is\;giving\;and\;t\;is\;the\;length\;of\;half\;time\\
15=100\times .5^(y/9000)\\
we \;use\; 15\; to \;mean\;15%\;and\; 100\; to\; show \;100%\;\\
Solving \;this\; we\; divide\; both \;sides\; by\; 100\; to\; get\\
15/100=.5^(y/9000)\\
taking\;\log \;both\;sides\\
 \log (15/100)=\log(.5)^(y/9000)\\
 \log(0.15)=(y/9000)\times \log.5\\
\therefore \; y=9000\times \log0.15/\log.5$

if answer is wright how find log value is any help me

Answer (score 0):

Your working out in correct. To evaluate a log your best approach is to use your calculator's log button. Lacking a suitable physical calculator there are many online ones which will be able to evaluate a log. If this is in a math competition where calculators are banned you can not evaluate it easily to arbitrary precision.

Comment: hy just i want answer can u help me..coz i didt get

Comment: What did you get when you typed $9000\times\log0.15\div\log0.5$ into your calculator?

Comment: i geeting wrong answer

Comment: What number did you get? What number are you expecting?

Comment: negative number i got this wrong

Comment: please answer  me plz

Comment: Make sure you are using brackets correctly on your calculator for the log. I.E. $9000\times\log(0.15)\div\log(0.5)$

Comment: Just posting the answer goes against the philosophy of StackExchange. If you just want someone to do your homework for you then there are many other sites. StackExchange is about educating people.